# Mentioning accepted conference papers that were not presented

Tags: graduate-admissions

If I have a paper accepted in a *known* conference of my field but am not able to present it at the the conference due to certain factors, should this be mentioned on my Master's application?

Also, where/how should this be mentioned?

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/the-fate-of-an-accepted-paper-not-being-presented

Comment: Was the paper withdrawn? Did someone else present it? Are you in a field like CS, where conference papers matter?

Comment: Field:CS. Not withdrawn, just that the funding process from the university is fairly long-drawn and may not get completed in time.

Answer (score 2):

If a paper is being withdrawn, then I would not give it any weight if I were reviewing a grad school application. The publications & presentations section of your CV is evidence of scholarly achievement, and so if the presentation didn't take place, there was no achievement -- I know of many conferences that have a nearly 100% acceptance rate, so having the paper accepted may simply be evidence of your ability to write coherently.

Comment: To counter your statement, presenting it isn't evidence of achievement either if the acceptance rate is 100%.

Answer (score 2):

If the paper isn't being withdrawn and will be included in the proceedings then **yes**, definitely include it!

Otherwise, you could list it as "In Preparation" in your Publication section if you plan on resubmitting it.