# What is the proper CV listing for an accepted paper that was not presented?

Tags: conference, cv

This question is similar to ones about [accepted papers not being presented](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/the-fate-of-an-accepted-paper-not-being-presented); however, one thing that other answers fail to mention is how to list the paper in your CV. Quite simply what is the appropriate way to list an unpresented paper where you are are a) solo author, or b) a co-author?

Comment: For specific details I suffered an injury that prevented my attendance at an IEEE conference where I was registered as a speaker. The paper does appear in the proceedings, but it remains to be seen if the organizers will submit it to Xplore. However, I'm trying to keep the question generic enough that it can address other situations.

Comment: _if the organizers will submit it to Xplore_ — Typically, once the camera-ready papers are sent to the publisher to build the proceedings, they're out of the organizers' hands.  Also: You paid the registration fee, so as for as IEEE-the-business is concerned, you've fulfilled your end of the publication agreement.

Comment: @JeffE It seems to be a bit hit-or-miss on that front for IEEE conferences. For this one the chair has requested that moderators keep track of no-shows so that the papers can be pulled form Xplore indexing. However, this might also be an odd situation since the registration fees are paid (I'm assuming it's a sunk cost as well) and it was literally just pesky bad luck.

Comment: Sorry to hear the chair is being a jerk, and that IEEE is willing to introduce errors into its index.  Have you communicated your situation to the chair/organizers?  Can you arrange for a backup speaker, or to present remotely via Skype/Hangout/similar?

Comment: @JeffE I don't think they are being a jerk, just super busy coordinating the conference. I have heard back from the section organizer though so i might see if I can work something out with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The paper does appear in the proceedings

Its appearance in the proceedings makes it a publication, so you can (and should) include it in your list of publications.

If you separately list your conference *presentations*, you can't include this paper in *that* list, because you didn't present it.  Similarly, if your list of conference publications indicates which papers you presented [for example, by writing "(presented)" or making the presenting author's name bold], you can't give that indication for this paper, because you didn't present it.

> where you are are a) solo author, or b) a co-author?

This is irrelevant.  The publication list in your CV should list all authors of each paper, ideally in the exact order they appear on the paper's title page.

**tl;dr: Just tell the truth.**

Comment: The format that my CV follows has the papers grouped by either "Presentations" or "Posters" and has the authors list along with "(Presenter)" next to the person who actually gave the talk. Would splitting things into "Papers", "Presentations" (most of these were abstracts), and "Posters" and then note the presenter accordingly make sense?

Comment: I strongly recommend listing "Conference publications", with a separate indicator for the papers you presented orally and the papers you presented as posters.  Your _publication_ record matters more than your _presentation_ record.  (Presentations/posters without associated publications should be listed separately)

Answer (score 1):

I am mainly going to answer what would I do in such a case.

IEEE allows the author to upload accepted version of paper in authors personal webpage. (I have one, so I will upload it. You can do it as well if you have one. Otherwise, upload a copy in Researchgate or arXiv).

After doing that, I will update my CV.

Conference Publications.

> R. Varadharajan, *Title of the paper*, Proceedings of IEEE, 2017. (Accepted, Preprint can be downloaded at [URL]).

Answer (score 1):

The only rule for CVs is that they must give an accurate record of what you have done. So the answer is simple: list it in a way that is accurate.